# java.util.logging.config

Tags: java, logging, properties, app-config

Is there a way to set the location of the properties file withough specifying a JVM param such as -Djava.util.logging.config.file=log.properties ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Per [the documentation](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html), you can configure the LogManager via the Preferences API.

```
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("logging.properties");
LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration(inputStream);
```